# How to manually specify a :delete request in the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

**Situation:**
I want to destroy the current session in Rails, and am currently signed into an admin model setup via devise.

I thought it would be enough to input `site.io/admins/sign_out` into the URL, but this assumes a `GET` request and doesn't work.

> No route matches [GET] "/admins/sign_out"

A `method: :delete` request needs to be made to destroy the session.

Can something be done like `site.io/admins/sign_out{action:delete}`?

**UPDATE**

Per request, this is the route related to admin.

```
devise_for :admins
```

Comment: can you share us the routes

Comment: Devise creates their own sessions accompanied by their routes. Can you add the view where you are using this.

Comment: I mean, I want to be able to sign out by manually typing a url into the browser. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not manually type in the link on the browser and log it out because in the browser you can't  specify `PUT` `POST` or `Delete`.If you define the logout path as `GET` Method you can directly enter the path and log it out as browser by default gives a `GET` method. you can do it on Rest Client like postman like below

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out.html
```

select method as `DELETE`

Answer (score 1):

To log out with devise you need to POST to `/admins/sign_out`. I use rails `link_to` to help with this.

```
<%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_admin_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

You could also do it without ERB or `link_to`

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/admins/sign_out">Log Out</a>
```

For `user` model, just replace `admin` with `user`

```
<%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

or

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">Log Out</a>
```

Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-sign_up-links-to-your-layout-template

Comment: I think the method called is `DELETE` in sign_out not `POST`.

Comment: It's an HTTP `POST` request with a `DELETE` method.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_admin_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inject `site.io/admins/sign_out` forcefully.

It will send you to the show action of the controller with  `Parameters: {"id"=>"sign_out"}`. Because It assumes that, it is a show action rather than calling the `Delete` function.

So, I think it is not possible, to forcefully use delete method directly from URL.